# May one walk under the Arch of Titus?

Tags: halacha, minhag, sources-mekorot, geography, churban-destruction

I have heard that it is prohibited ([or at least that the custom is not](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v40/mj_v40i60.html#CSV)) to walk under the [Arch of Titus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_of_titus) in Rome. Is this accurate? If so, what is the source? Would it make a difference if a large group were to march under it in an act of defiance?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_of_titus#Significance

Comment: The Gemara prohibits walking under Asheirah trees - perhaps this is related?

Answer (score 10):

My rabbinic sources in Rome tell me that there is no written source, but that this is local minhag.  --SF

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, steven fine, and thanks for the answer! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. You may especially be interested in some of [our 536 history questions](http://yodeya.com/questions/tagged/history). If you're the same Steven Fine mentioned in [the other answer](http://yodeya.com/a/18154), could you identify yourself as such, so readers know whose sources are "My rabbinic sources"? Please also consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account: it will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 9):

[Dr. Steven Fine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Fine), my Classical Jewish History prof at YU, wrote in this year's Tisha Bav [To-Go](http://www.yutorah.org/togo/tishabav/) (published by YU's CJF) the following:

> For centuries, Jews avoided the Arch of Titus, refusing to walk under
>   it and thus to give honor to Titus. The Arch symbolized the debasement
>   of Judaism and the beginning of our woes. This situation was
>   reinforced by the Church, for which the Arch came to symbolize the
>   transfer of Divine authority from Jerusalem to the Church of Rome, and
>   with it, the Divine punishment imposed upon the Jews for rejecting
>   Jesus. Things began to change in the modern world. From the nineteenth
>   century on, Jews came to see the Arch’s Menorah in a much more
>   positive light, as a symbol for Judaism. For Jewish traditionalists
>   and Zionists, its unique form symbolized a hope for national
>   restoration in the Land of Israel. The only “archaeologically
>   accurate” representation of the Temple vessels then known, the Arch
>   was reimagined as a Jewish treasure and a link to a glorious past.
>   Jews reproduced the Arch of Titus Menorah within synagogues and many
>   other communal contexts. After long deliberation, in 1949, the Arch of
>   Titus Menorah was chosen as the symbol for the new State of Israel.
>   Bringing the Menorah “home,” at least figuratively, Israeli authors
>   and artists saw the Menorah as a metaphor for the entire Jewish
>   people, and its reappropriation as Israel’s national symbol as part of
>   the “ingathering of exiles” that the new State saw as its mission.<sup>51</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>51</sup> This history is masterfully related by team member Alec Mishory in
>   his Lo and Behold: Zionist Icons and Visual Symbols in Israeli Culture
>   (Tel Aviv: Yediot Aharonot, 2000), 138-96, in Hebrew. An abbreviated
>   translation appears at:
>   http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/History/emblem.html.

I first accessed this article yesterday (10 Av 5772).

Comment: Though see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8155